# Conditional statement inside WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq

Consider the following records:
[image: Records]

The outlined records are the same gameobject but they have different configuration names (the record where ConfigurationName is null is a copy from my original table).

```
string customName= "Config1";

string draftName = "Draft_" + id;

   var list = db.JoinedGameObjects
                            .Where(x => x.TBUploads_ID == id)
                            .Where(x => x.ConfigurationName.Equals(customName) || x.ConfigurationName == null)
                            .Select(x => new GameObjectViewModel()
                            {
                                ID = x.ID,
                                GameObjectName = x.GameObjectName,
                                Category = x.Category,
                                Family = x.Family,
                                Type = x.Type,
                                MetaTypeJson = x.MetaTypeJson,
                                MaterialsJson = x.MaterialsJson,
                                MetadataVisibilityJson = x.MetadataVisibilityJson,
                                Visible = x.joined_Visible ?? x.Visible
                            }).ToList();
```

This code gets all records where ConfigurationName equals my customName variable or where ConfigurationName = null. However, this is not what I want.

I'll try to explain the desired outcome with an example.

I first want to check if there is a record with this ID with ConfigurationName equal to draftName (if true select this record), if not check if there is a record with this ID with ConfigurationName equal to customName (if true select this gameobject), if not take the record with this ID where ConfigurationName is null.

Can someone guide me in the right direction or provide a working example?

Comment: Are you trying to get one entry by its ID? Or a list ob entries each with its respective ID?

Comment: i want one record from each unique ID

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already have a working concept, just add a `draftName` comparison to your `Where` condition.
It will apply conditions in order defined in `Where` function

```
.Where(x => x.ConfigurationName.Equals(draftName) || x.ConfigurationName.Equals(customName) || x.ConfigurationName == null)
```

### Edit #1:

This should reflect what the OP wants. 
For the sake of brevity, I used custom `Person` class and simplified the code example, so the concept should be easy to understand:

```
public class Person { 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then the rest:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = null},
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "Mike"},
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "John"},

    new Person{Id = 2, Name= null},
    new Person{Id = 2, Name= "Peter"},
};

//filter values
string filter1 = "Mike";
string filter2 = "John";
string filter3 = null;

var byPriority = people
    .Where(p=> p.Name == filter1 || p.Name == filter2 || p.Name == filter3)
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Name == filter1)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Name == filter2)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Name == filter3);

var oneByIId = byPriority
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

The key here is to order the records by conditions priority. Then group the records and take the first one from each group

### Edit #2

In some cases, LINQ to SQL may fail when comparing to `NULL`, in such a case, modify null comparing parts as this:

```
var byPriority = people
    .Where(p=> p.Name == filter1 || p.Name == filter2 || object.Equals(p.Name,filter3))
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Name == filter1)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.Name == filter2)
    .ThenByDescending(p => object.Equals(p.Name,filter3));

var oneByIId = byPriority
    .GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(g => g.First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This will not work in the way the author intended (at least to my understanding). This will take any object any of the conditions apply to. Anyway, if there is an object `(3, Draft_3)` and there is an object `(3, "Config1")` and and object `(3, null)` your query will take alle of them, while the author would only want the first one (which does not nescessarily have to appear first, hence `.First()` won't do.

Comment: That is right. I will try to modify my answer accordingly

Comment: @PaulKertscher your're right that's exactly what I need

Comment: @TomasChabada i tried your solution but i get this error: System.NotSupportedException: 'The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.'

Comment: @TomasChabada FirstOrDefault doesn't throw the error but it returns all records. Not one per unique ID

Comment: @CédricKamermans can you please send me your actual linq query?

Comment: @TomasChabada 

`var byPriority = db.JoinedGameObjects
                        .Where(x => x.TBUploads_ID == id)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == draftName)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == configurationName)
                        .ThenByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == null);

                    var oneByIId = byPriority
                        .GroupBy(p => p.ID)
                        .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ToList();`

Comment: @CédricKamermans Add ConfigurationName filtering condition to `byPriority` query:db.JoinedGameObjects .Where(x => x.TBUploads_ID == id).Where(x => x.ConfigurationName.Equals(drafrName) || ...)

Comment: @TomasChabada using your new query did give me the correct amount of records however, it seems that there are some duplicates and some IDs are missing. This is my output (just the IDs):

795749
795749
795750
795752
795753
795754
795755
795756
795757
795758

Also, the given records were those with Configuration value null. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @CédricKamermans Hard to say when I don't see the code, but grouping shouldn't return two groups with same key, so it seems there is something another causing this

Comment: @TomasChabada 

`var byPriority = db.JoinedGameObjects.Where(x => x.TBUploads_ID == id).Where(x => x.ConfigurationName.Equals(draftName) || x.ConfigurationName.Equals(configurationName) || x.ConfigurationName.Equals(null)).OrderByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == draftName).ThenByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == configurationName).ThenByDescending(x => x.ConfigurationName == null);

var oneByIId = byPriority.GroupBy(p => p.ID) .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()) .ToList();`

Comment: @TomasChabada that just results one record because they all have the same upload_ID

Comment: @CédricKamermans check my new Update, null comparison is maybe an issue here